# Is there a port of libfaketime to OSX?

Tags: macos

Is there a port of libfaketime to OSX? http://www.code-wizards.com/projects/libfaketime/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I ported it.

http://github.com/dbrashear/libfaketime/

Answer (score 1):

On [freshmeat](http://freshmeat.net/projects/libft) libfaketime lists its platforms as Linux and POSIX. Since OSX is [listed as fully POSIX compliant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX#Fully_POSIX-compliant), it should be perfectly usable as-is.

**EDIT**

if `clock_gettime` is the only problematic function and you're feeling fool-hardy, you could try this little [hack](http://www.wanderinghill.com/wp/?p=29):

```
#if _POSIX_TIMERS > 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tp);
#else
struct timeval tv;
gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
tp.tv_sec = tv.tv_sec;
tp.tv_nsec = tv.tv_usec*1000;
#endif
```

Comment: Unfortunately, OSX doesn't implement clock_gettime which libfaketime requires so it doesn't compile. Unfortunately it is a known issue: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2235198?threadID=2235198 Also for more information: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Cipb1gLFRJoJ:www.wand.net.nz/~smr26/wordpress/2009/01/19/monotonic-time-in-mac-os-x/+OSX+clock_gettime&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&source=www.google.com

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not false advertising. UNIX 03 does not require `clock_gettime`. UNIX 03 certification requires conformance with POSIX.1-2001. In that version of POSIX, `clock_gettime` is part of the Timers option; i.e. it is optional, not mandatory. In POSIX.1-2008, the Timers option is merged into the Base specification. Future versions of UNIX certification will likely require `clock_gettime`, but UNIX 03 doesn't. :(

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I see what's fool-hardy about this workaround, except that it should be `#elif _XOPEN_UNIX > 0` or `#elif _XOPEN_VERSION > 600` (since `gettimeofday` is an XSI extension).